# How to scale background image in Aspose Pdf FloatingBox

Tags: c#, pdf, aspose

I'm trying to set up the SVG waterstamp in specific position, but can't place it accurately

```
            using (var pngStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                outstream.Streams.First().CopyTo(pngStream);
                FloatingBox boxStamp = new FloatingBox(200, 180);
                boxStamp.Border = new BorderInfo(BorderSide.All, borderWidth: (float)0.5);
                boxStamp.ZIndex = 20;
                boxStamp.Top = _top; boxStamp.Left = _left;
                boxStamp.BackgroundImage = new Aspose.Pdf.Image
                {
                    ImageScale = 2,
                    //FixWidth = 400,
                    //FixHeight = 300,
                    //ImageScale = 1,
                    ImageStream = pngStream,
                };
                page.Paragraphs.Add(boxStamp);
                pdf.Save("stamped.pdf");
```

[image]